# Show that the following sequence is monotonically decreasing $a_{n}=\frac{2 \sqrt{n} - 1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to show that the following sequence is monotonically decereasing.

$$\frac{2 \sqrt{n} - 1}{n}\geq\frac{2 \sqrt{n+1} - 1}{n+1}$$

I was trying to solve this equation but couldn't get anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2 \sqrt{n} - 1}{n}>\frac{2 \sqrt{n+1} - 1}{n+1}$$

$$2(n+1)\sqrt{n} - 2 n\sqrt{n+1}> 1 $$

$$2\sqrt{n(n+1)}(\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n})> 1 $$

$$\frac{2\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt{n}}> 1 $$

$$2\sqrt{n(n+1)}>\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt{n}$$

$$2>{1\over \sqrt{n+1}} +{1\over \sqrt{n}}$$

And this is true since ${1\over \sqrt{n+1}}<1$ and ${1\over \sqrt{n}}\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\frac {2\sqrt x-1}x$$

And let $g(x)=\ln f(x)=\ln (2\sqrt x-1)-\ln x$

Then $$g'(x)=\frac 1{ (2 x-\sqrt x)}-\frac 1x$$

And it is easily seen that $x>1\implies g'(x)<0$.  Indeed, (assuming x>1) we note that $$\frac 1{ (2 x-\sqrt x)}-\frac 1x<0\iff \frac 1{ (2 x-\sqrt x)}<\frac 1x$$

Since $x>1$ we may cross multiply to see that this is equivalent to:

$$x<2x-\sqrt x$$ which in turn is equivalent to: $$\sqrt x<x$$ which is true for $x>1$.

Noting that $f(x)$ is decreasing iff $g(x)$ is we see that we are done (I'll leave that point as an exercise).

Comment: Can you elaborate "it is easily seen" part? Also you can extend the note with explaination: if h(x)=g(f(x)) and g is monotonically increasing function, then h is monotonically decreasing if and only if f is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: @croraf  I will edit to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{n+1}\ <\ \sqrt n + \frac 1{2\cdot\sqrt n} $$
hence
$$ \frac{2\cdot\sqrt{n+1}-1}{n+1}\ <
       \ \frac{2\cdot\sqrt n + \frac 1{\sqrt n}-1}{n+1}\ = $$

$$ \frac{2\cdot\sqrt n-1}n\ -\ \frac{\frac 1{\sqrt n}+\frac 1n}{n+1}\,\ \le
       \,\ \frac{2\cdot\sqrt n-1}n $$

for every $\ n=1\ 2\ \ldots$.